# Unique way of identifing an iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm working on an app that has a code authentication, in order to do that I have to know what device has activated the code. Is there a unique ID or something like that, that does not change even if the app gets reinstalled?

Comment: You can get this answer from below linke.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795707/how-to-get-unchanged-device-id-from-ios7-device-programmatically)

Comment: From what link?

Comment: UDID is unique for each device.

Comment: Ok i found the post from 6 years ago, but do you know how to use it? because it is not working for me

Comment: You can use the new [DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) API but it is iOS 11 only

Answer (score -1):

You can use the identifierforvendor for this

```
UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
```